# Adding string numbers in a list, using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Is there a simpler way possible to just add numbers which are regarded as strings but also integer by python? It doesn't let me add it, maybe because of the way I converted the integer to string and then a list?

I have done this so far:

```
function_menu()
print()
numbers = str(number)
lists = []
lists.extend(numbers)
addition = sum(lists)
    average = addition / len(lists)
    print(average)
```

Comment: Is there a reason you need to convert the ints into a string before inserting into the list?

Comment: i think so because that is the only way for me to use my way to turn the ints into a list. is there a better way to turn it from integer straight to a list? a simple way? thanks.

Comment: also i was just searching now and i found this but its a bit complicated :
def avg(list):
    sum = 0
    for elm in list:
        sum += elm
    print('The average element of the list is: ', + str(sum/(len(list)*1.0)))

Comment: I've flagged this as unclear. The code sample you've posted isn't even valid python. Could you edit it to show the minimum possible code necessary to demonstrate the problem you're having? Also, "I'm desperate, this is urgent" doesn't add anything to your question, please don't post things like that.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Answer (score 0):

With list comprehension you could do something like this

```
addition = sum([int(num) for num in lists])
```

A simple way to convert your number into a list of separate digits is

```
digits = [int(digit) for digit in str(number)]

# average then becomes
average = sum(digits)/len(digits)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just convert your individual string digits to integers before turning them into a list:

```
numbers = [int(digit) for digit in str(number)]
addition = sum(numbers)
average = addition / len(numbers)
# etc.
```